# Jetty + jax-ws affects jsp compilation - it now needs ant?

Tags: java, jsp, jax-ws, embedded-jetty

We have just upgraded to the newest jax-ws code from metro, but for some reason we now have to ship ant too.   This appears to be needed for the jsp compilation.

Without it we get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/BuildListener
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.initJavaCompiler(Compiler.java:742)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.<init>(Compiler.java:131)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.createCompiler(JspCompilationContext.java:288)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:605)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:360)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440)
    ......
```

Is there any way to remove the dependency on ant?

How does the jax-ws affect the jsp libraries which have not changed?

Thanks
Neil

Comment: It is Jasper (the JSP compiler) that uses ant, not Metro.

Comment: We didnt change the jsp jars only the jax-ws jars.  Somehow it appears the jax-ws changes the compiler used by default.

Comment: What is the smallest example you can provide, showing this behavior?

Comment: I dont think its a coding problem, but an infrastructure one.  We run an embedded jetty server with jsp + ws code and something has changed while we moved to the newer jax-ws version which affects jsp compilation.

Comment: I'm going to undo the jax-ws changes and start again (step - by - step).  Something else must be happening.   No source code from jax-ws references the Compiler class.

Comment: You can see from the stack trace that it is the Jetty container wanting to compile the JSP page.  This is _before_ any JAX-WS annotations come into play.   Did you put together the Jetty installation yourself?

Comment: Yes, we embed jetty into a very large server which uses lots of legacy C code.  Its a very complex setup :)

Answer (score 0):

Jetty states the "compiler - Determined at runtime. For Jetty is the eclipse jdt compiler."  See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Jsp+Configuration.

It appears that during our build the core-3.1.1.jar was not being packaged (which must have been caused by the jax-ws changes).  When this is missing there is no warning from jetty, instead jasper falls back to trying to use ant (which then causes the class not found exception).

When I manually include the core-3.1.1.jar into the installation the jsp compilation works.

Comment: I would suggest you include a sanity check of the web server in your integration test suite which runs automatically on a regular basis.